# Run a method with View Parameter oncreate Android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run onClick method in oncreate but the onclick method has View param. i am confused on how to pass the View through oncreate.

Specifying onclick through xml works. but my objective is:
I have checkbox in Mainactivity. and oncreate the system should check if the checkbox.checked() then run the onclick method. so it will facilitate the user to not click on the button each time they open the app. if it is not checked so the user should do the initial configuration and click the button upon clicking the checkbox will be checked.

Here is my code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
        if (LoginCheck.isChecked()){
            OnClickLogin(View);
        }
    }

public void OnClickLogin(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            LoginProcess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            LoginProcess.setText("Connecting...Please wait!");
            LoginResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            String pass = editPass.getText().toString();
            String user = editUser.getText().toString();
            String dbname = editDbname.getText().toString();
            String dburl = editurl.getText().toString();

            odoo = new OdooUtility(dburl, "common");

            loginTaskId = odoo.login(listener,
                    dbname, user, pass);

            SharedData.setKey(MainActivity.this, "password", pass);
            SharedData.setKey(MainActivity.this, "username", user);
            SharedData.setKey(MainActivity.this, "database", dbname);
            SharedData.setKey(MainActivity.this, "serverAddress", dburl);

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the view in the onClickLogin? Can you also post the XML?

Comment: do a ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id)).setOnClickListener(this); your activity should implement OnClickListener, and in the onClick pass the view of onClick to onclickLogin

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the button view from id to the method OnClickLogin.
from onCreate() just call this method.

`this.OnClickLogin(findViewById(R.id.button_id))`